# Dependency injection in a CommandLineRunner failed

Tags: java, spring

I would like to develop a "batch" with Spring Boot. I have a class that implements a `CommandLineRunner` who need a `@Service` class.

Here is the code :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CarmindBatch implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Inject
    private VehicleDataBatchService vehicleDataBatchService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {

        vehicleDataBatchService.start(args[0]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(CarmindBatch.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the service :

```
@Service
public class DefaultVehicleDataBatchService implements VehicleDataBatchService {

    @Inject
    private VehicleDataRepository vehicleDataRepository;

    @Inject
    private Mapper mapper;

    @Override
    public void start(String path) {

        // Convert a file to a list of beans and put them in database...
    }

}
```

My problem is that a `BeanCreationException` occured when I launch `CarmindBatch` but it work well when I try with a JUnit test who inject `VehicleDataBatchService`.

The stack trace :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carmindBatch': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fr.carmind.api.service.batch.VehicleDataBatchService fr.carmind.api.batch.CarmindBatch.vehicleDataBatchService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [fr.carmind.api.service.batch.VehicleDataBatchService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at fr.carmind.api.batch.CarmindBatch.main(CarmindBatch.java:25) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fr.carmind.api.service.batch.VehicleDataBatchService fr.carmind.api.batch.CarmindBatch.vehicleDataBatchService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [fr.carmind.api.service.batch.VehicleDataBatchService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [fr.carmind.api.service.batch.VehicleDataBatchService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: What is the package of DefaultVehicleDataBatchService?

Comment: @JBNizet : fr.carmind.api.service.batch.impl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application class is in the package `fr.carmind.api.batch`.

Your service class in in the package `fr.carmind.api.service.batch.impl`.

Since you didn't specify any package to scan, the default is to scan the application class packages and all its sub-packages. But the service class is not in a sub-package. So it isn't found.

Put the service class in a sub-package of the application class, or specify which packages must be scanned using a `@ComponentScan` annotation.