# Sending Gmail with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gmail

I am creating an example of sending email to spring.

I first declared this in dependencies. The program uses 'idea' and is created by selecting 'gradle-project'. ile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

The bean was declared as Java instead of xml.

```
@Configuration
public class MailConfig {
@Bean
public static JavaMailSender mailSender(){
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPort(587);//465
    mailSender.setUsername("??????@gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPassword("??????");

    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    return mailSender;
  }
}
```

The controller:

```
@Controller
public class MailController{
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)

public void sendMail(String from,String to, String subject, String text) {
    try{

        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom(from);
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(text);
        mailSender.send(message);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("개시ㅂ라");
    }
  }
}
```

**main**

```
MailController a = new 
a.sendMail("gusxo5243@gmail.com","taesea5241@naver.com","제목","내용");
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: We absolutely can't help with the input you have given so far.

Comment: Every time I run the program, there is no response.
Only 'nullpoinException' is displayed, and no email is sent.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an object of a class that you annotated with one of Spring's stereotype annotations (e.g. Repository, Controller, Component, Service) with `new` operator, the created object will not be a Spring bean - Spring will NOT take care of dependencies, it will not wire your JavaMailSender instance into your MailController!

If you really want to try out mailsending in your main() method, use Spring's `CommandLineRunner` to execute some code right after startup of your Spring Boot application. See example below: A `CommandLineRunner` Spring bean will be created and your Spring configured `MailController` instance will be injected as a method parameter. This instance should have it's `JavaMailSender` property already set, since Spring took care of it at application startup (bean creation, dependency injection / bean wiring).

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SendMailTestDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SendMailTestDriver.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner(MailController mailController) {
        return args -> {
            mailController.sendMail("gusxo5243@gmail.com","taesea5241@naver.com","xxx","yyy");
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added under @bean to my application.java file, but I get the error 'Can not resolve symbol' mailController '.

Comment: what's that package name of your main class (containing 'public static void main(...)  + annotated with @SpringBootApplication)  and class MailController.java ?

Comment: pls ensure that your annotated beans are found by component scanning: read this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38029328/dependency-injection-in-a-commandlinerunner-failed

Comment: The main file and the controller file are in the same package.
package name is com.example.aaasd

Comment: try to explicitly specifiy the package(s) of the classes, that have stereotype annotations. e.g. add @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.aaasd"} to your application class

Comment: Where should I put ')'?  and  if i put  @component  anywhere?

Comment: sorry, like this: @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.aaasd"})

please read the post I mentioned above... if you do not specify packages to be scanned, there are defaults to which Spring will fallback